# custom script on docker run

Tags: php, zend-framework, docker, composer-php

I am trying to install the skeleton application of Zend Framework 3 with Docker.

The installation works fine, but I'm not able to run some composer scripts. In the `composer.json` there are some custom composer scripts, which should be generally launched with

```
composer cs-fix
```

I would like to lauch there commands with the [Composer Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/), using

```
docker run --rm -ti --volume $PWD:/app composer cs-fix
```

When I try to do this, I obtain the following error

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 60: exec: cs-fix: not found
```

Is my command wrong?

Comment: post your Dockerfile and your docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: @user2915097 I'm using the Docker image I linked, you can find the `Dockerfile` and the `docker-entrypoint.sh` here: https://github.com/composer/docker

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Instead of trying to run the custom composer script, I need to use the special `run-script` command, as in

```
docker run --rm -it --volume $PWD:/app composer run-script "cf-fix"
```